# How use local views built with gem devise in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

I am following a guide for oauth google, using `gem 'devise'` in rails.
All is ok, but now that I cannot change the graphics with the views,
I realised that the controller that I'm using, redirects its method to other controllers and other views that aren't in my app, but are in other path (devise gem). **how can I redirect all in my app?**

to explain myself this is part of the result of command `rake routes`:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                 new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
                     user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
             destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
```

the controller **Action** is mapped on  devise/session  controller that isn't in my app but in the path

```
 ".rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/controller..."
```

so that call the views that are on the directory as

```
".rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/devise-4.6.2/app/views..."
```

but I want that controllers to use my views.

this is the `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks =>  "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  resources :homepage, only: [:index]
  resources :schedules, only: [:index, :edit]
  resources :notes, only: [:index, :edit]
  resources :accounts, only: [:index, :edit]

  root :to => 'homepage#index'

end
```

This is the only controller that I have created:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Google") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    end
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

Comment: You should read the README on the home page of Devise gem more carefully. They clearly show you how to override the controller and views.

Answer (score 2):

Devise allows overriding views and controllers. Usually it's sufficient to override the views by adding files like `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`, there's a generator to copy default views to your app:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

See devise's [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) for more details.